# Although columns and values match, Oracle gives me error ORA-00947

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to save log table my db data before updating it. For logging, additionally, I want to save update date and time. But oracle gives me "ORA-00947: not enough values" error.

I searched that error on Google, but all answers mention about number of values and columns doesn't match case. In my case, they match.
Where is I'm wrong?

```
    INSERT INTO db.eee_log (process_date, process_time, id, name, type)
      VALUES(trunc(sysdate),
             TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS.FF5'),
             (select p.id, p.name, p.type
                from db.eee p
               where id = 22
                 and name = 'xxx'
                 and type = 'xx'));
```

Comment: You cannot use one select statement to provide values for more than one column specified in the `insert` statement the way you use it. You need to decide between using only `values()` clause or rewrite your query using only `select` statement.

Comment: Why are you storing date and time in separate columns? You also seem to be inserting the same values you're filtering on, so do you actually need to hit the `eee` table at all, or can you just insert the filter values directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of values doesn't match the number of columns. The subquery you're doing within the values clause is seen as a single column expression, not three as you expect. To use a subquery like that it would have to return a single value, which would go into a single column.

You can generate all of the values from your source table, and not use a subquery or values clause at all:

```
INSERT INTO db.eee_log (process_date, process_time, id, name, type)
SELECT trunc(sysdate),TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS.FF5'),p.id, p.name, p.type
from db.eee p
where p.id = 22
and p.name = 'xxx'
and p.type = 'xx';
```

---

Your example may be overly simplified, but if that is what you are really doing and there is always exactly one row in `eee` for the values you supply, you can use the literals you're currently filtering on directly in the values clause instead:

```
INSERT INTO db.eee_log (process_date, process_time, id, name, type)
VALUES (trunc(sysdate),TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS.FF5'), 22, 'xxx', 'xx');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
  INSERT INTO db.eee_log (process_date, process_time, id, name, type)
     select
        trunc(sysdate),
        TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS.FF5'),
        p.id,
        p.name, 
        p.type
     from db.eee p
     where id = 22
     and name = 'xxx'
     and type = 'xx'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO db.eee_log  (process_date, process_time, id, name, type)
SELECT trunc(sysdate), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS.FF5'), p.id, p.name, p.type from db.eee p
            where id = 22
            and name = 'xxx'
            and type = 'xx'
```